# R string split manipulation in a data frame does not work

Tags: r, string, dataframe, dplyr

Here is a simple testing case.

Was planning to split and extract only the first part of each string.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
test = data.frame(x= c('a b', 'c d'),stringsAsFactors = F)

test
    x
1 a b
2 c d

test %>% mutate(y = str_split(x,'\\s+')[[1]][1])
    x y
1 a b a
2 c d a
```

Was expecting something like:

```
    x y
1 a b a
2 c d c
```

Comment: The output of `str_split` is a `list`, so your indexing is wrong.

Comment: @Chen you should use Aranda library: `library(splitstackshape);cSplit(test, 'x', ' ')`

Comment: @ColonelBeauvel I agree, but it's "Ananda" :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nowadays there are various packaged functions for splitting columns into pieces.  Here you could use the `separate()` function from the *tidyr* package.  Since you want the first value of a split on the spaces, you can just remove everything after the first space.

```
tidyr::separate(test, x, "y", "\\s.*", FALSE, extra = "drop")
#     x y
# 1 a b a
# 2 c d c
```

Comment: Kids these days with all their fancy `separate` functions. Back in my day I had to `strsplit` by hand, four miles in the snow.... grumble grumble.

Comment: Up hill, both ways?  Those pesky package rascals.

Answer (score 2):

str_split returns a list where each element corresponds to an element in the original atomic vector. As such you will need to use `lapply` or similar to index appropriately

```
test %>% mutate(y = unlist(lapply(str_split(x,'\\s+'),'[[',1)))
```

Comment: `test %>% mutate(y=vapply(strsplit(x,"\\s+"),\`[\`, 1, FUN.VALUE=character(1)))` - `vapply` ftw.

Answer (score 2):

We can also use `sub`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(test)[, y:= sub('\\s+.*', '', x)]
test
#     x y
#1: a b a
#2: c d c
```